# How to comment on a photo and like a photo

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-comments

I have researched [in the doc](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/Comment/) but i could not find out anything.

I want user to comment others' photo and like their photo. How can i do this?
I am using php-sdk also graph api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried going through the [`photo`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/) object document?
[Comments](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/#comments):

> You can write to the PHOTO_ID/comments connection to post a comment to
>   the photo by issuing an HTTP POST request with the publish_stream
>   permission and following parameters.

[Likes](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/#likes):

> You can like a photo by issuing a HTTP POST request to PHOTO_ID/likes
>   connection with the publish_stream permission. No parameters
>   necessary.